# WIX bootstrapper project install framework and fail to install my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

Below is my complete `Bundle.wxs` of my Bootstrapper project.

```
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
         xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
      <Bundle UpgradeCode="493993E8-50F0-43B2-BEF7-A57F4EAD374D" Name="MYAPPlication Name" Version="1.0.0.0" IconSourceFile="D:\..\Resources\Application_icon.ico">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
          <!--<Payload Name="BootstrapperCore.config" SourceFile="$(var.MYAPPlication .TargetDir)\MYAPPlication .BootstrapperCore.config"/>-->
          <Payload SourceFile="D:\..\MYAPPlication.msi"/>
          <!--<Payload SourceFile="NetfxLicense.rtf"/>-->
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
      <MsiPackage  Name="MSIApplication.msi" Compressed="yes" SourceFile="D:\.\MSIApplication.msi" Vital="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT"  Value="1"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
    <WixVariable
        Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId"
        Value="Netfx4Full" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />

    <util:RegistrySearch
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
        Value="Version"
        Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
        Value="Version"
        Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion"
        Win64="yes" />

    <PackageGroup
        Id="Netfx4Full">
      <ExePackage
          Id="Netfx4Full"
          Cache="no"
          Compressed="no"
          PerMachine="yes"
          Permanent="yes"
          Vital="yes"
          SourceFile="D:\...\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
          DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
          DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

After building the above bootstrap project i am getting two files,1) The Framework i included (`dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe`)and another is an 2)EXE File with MYApplication name and ICON (`MYAPPlication.exe`). I removed the framework in my system and double clicked the `MYAPPlication.exe`,it installed the framework and closed.My actual msi application (`MSIApplication.msi`) what i included is not installed after framework install.

I already have a setup project and that outputs the .msi file(`MSIApplication.msi`).I have added this msi in `Bundle.wxs`.

I need to install framework if  not exist and follows it should install my msi application(`MSIApplication.msi`),when the user double clicks `MYAPPlication.exe`.Is it possible with wix bootstraper project.